# How to remove quotes from a string

Tags: python-3.x, cx-oracle

I am running an insert query towards an oracle DB, where I am getting an error which says column not allowed here.

the value I am entering for date is :

`'ToDate('11/01/21','dd/mm/yyyy')'` - > I get column error
`ToDate('11/01/21','dd/mm/yyyy')` -> I don't get error if I remove the quotes.

as the value is coming from a dictionary I want to know how can I remove the quotes at the end . I tried `strip()` its not working looks like it doesn't think that quotes are there at the end.

Comment: `To_Date` is a predefined conversion within Oracle DB, what do you mean by `ToDate`? And can you edit the question with the details how you invoke the insert statement...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the method

```
your_string_name.replace('"', "")
```

Comment: Tried Not working i am getting the same value as output